# How to know when replica set initial sync completed

Tags: mongodb

From the MongoDB documentation:

> At this point, the mongod will perform an initial sync. The length of the initial sync process depends on the size of the database and network connection between members of the replica set.

[Source](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/#automatically-sync-a-member)

My question in very simple, how can I know when it's safe to `stepDown` the `PRIMARY` member of my replica set? I just upgrated my secondary to use WiredTiger.

Output of `rs.status()`:

```
{
    "set" : "m0",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-03-18T09:59:21.486Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "example.com",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 4642,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1426672500, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-03-18T09:55:00Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1426668268, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2015-03-18T08:44:28Z"),
            "configVersion" : 7,
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "example.com"",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 1309,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1426672500, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-03-18T09:55:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-03-18T09:59:20.968Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-03-18T09:59:20.762Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "syncingTo" : "example.com"",
            "configVersion" : 7
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "example.com"",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 7,
            "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
            "uptime" : 4640,
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-03-18T09:59:21.009Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-03-18T09:59:21.238Z"),
            "pingMs" : 59,
            "configVersion" : 7
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

While performing the inital sync, the status is `RECOVERING`

Comment: Not quite. `STARTUP1` and `STARTUP2` may be seen, too.